# Select where string contains substring using Panache

Tags: sql, jpa, substring, contains, quarkus-panache

I'm currently trying to implement the function "Load all X where X.name contains y" using a Ms SQL-Server and the Panache-Repositories.
I know the SQL-Query "SELECT * FROM X WHERE X.name LIKE '%0y%'" works, but I can't get it to work using the Panache-Query.
I've tried

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class XRepository implements PanacheRepository<X> {

  public List<X> listWhereLike(String like) {
    return list("name like ?1", "%" + like + "%");
  }

  public List<X> listWhereLike(String like) {
    return list("name like %?1%", like);
  }

  public List<X> listWhereLike(String like) {
    return list("contains(name, ?1)", like);
  }
}
```

but none of them work.
They either throw an exception because of the unexpected character '%' or '(' or they simply return an empty list.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

This is the solution , you just  need to put the pattern in a String before adding it to the query;

```
  public List<X> listWhereLike(String like) {

    String searchInput = "%" + like + "%";

    return list("name like ?1", searchInput );
  }
```